# Does MongoDB's update atomicity apply to both query and modification?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB has support for atomic updates. I.e. I can be sure that when a document is updated no other update will overwrite my previous change. My question relates to the combination of query and update statement, and is best illustrated by the example shown below.

```
db.foo.update(
{ state : 1, players: { $size: 2 } } , 
{ $push: { players : { new player document } } }, 
false , true );
```

In the above example, I only want to push a new player into a collection of players, if the number of players equals 2. Given the above query and update statement, is it possible that two simultaneous updates both push a player onto the same document, because at the time of reading the document its players $size is 2? I.e. does the atomicity span across the query and update part of the update statement or not?

**Edit** More in-depth sequence of events:

Consider firing the same update twice (U1 and U2) at the same time. Is the following sequence of events possible or not?

1. U1 finds that document #1 matches the query portion of the update
   statement.
2. U2 finds that document #1 matches the query portion of
   the update statement.
3. U1 pushes a new player in document #1.
4. U2 pushes a new player in document #1.

The end result is that document #1 contains one more player than expected, because both U1 and U2 were under the impression that document #1 contains only two players.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've asked this question on the mongodb-user group. http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/e61e220dc0f6f64c

According to the answer by Marc (who works at 10gen) the situation described by me cannot occur.

> The situation that you described is not possible; there is no danger 
>    of both updates modifying the same document.

Answer (score 1):

Update: not sure of my knowledge anymore... See ["The ABA Nuance"](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-TheABANuance). Please don't accept this answer (or my comment below) as it is probably not correct. Would love to be corrected.

---

Your explanation of atomic is incorrect (*I can be sure that when a document is updated no other update will overwrite my previous change*). Other updates can (and will) overwrite your change. But they won't do it in a way that would interfere with integrity of your query.

It is important to know that MongoDB updates are [atomic on single document](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations). So when a document matches your query, it is "locked" and ready for an update. Note that your update (`$push`) works inside the same document that was locked. When update is finished, lock is released.

I am not sure I understand "*does the atomicity span across the query and update part of the update statement or not*", but: atomic means that **other** queries can't mess with our query. Our query can change data that is "locked" by itself.

Disclaimer: I am not privy to internal mechanisms MongoDB uses to ensure this atomicity, so this description might be lacking from technical viewpoint (especially in connection to locking) - but it is valid conceptually. This is how it works from external viewpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've updated my question with a sequence of events, which I hope clarifies things a bit. I now realise that what I am asking about is not atomicity, but a transaction (lock) at the document level.

Comment: Yes, that indeed clarifies the question. You have nothing to worry about. Nothing can alter the document between find and update (steps 2 and 4) or the operation would not be atomic. If it doesn't work this way, then it is a bug and should be reported as such.

Answer (score 0):

With the sequence of events that you write down, you can indeed have one player too many. The update's "find" and "update" work very much like doing it yourself with a "find" and then an "update" on each of the documents that you're iterating over. You probably want to have a look at the "$atomic" operator: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-ApplyingtoMultipleObjectsAtOnce

Comment: Note that OP is issuing only 2 updates (U1 and U2), the steps are just there to illustrate possible conflict.